# Infinite loop that fills tmp folder in Ubuntu with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

Just created a fresh install of Ubuntu.  Installed python and selenium, went to run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox('/usr/bin/')
browser.get('http://www.ubuntu.com/')


browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

when i run it, it just hangs in the terminal and then when I press Control-C it says:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox('/usr/bin/')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 127, in __init__
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 78, in __init__
    ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 189, in copytree
    copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 189, in copytree
    copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 189, in copytree
    copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 192, in copytree
    copy2(srcname, dstname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 84, in copyfile
    copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If I don't kill the program and it fills my tmp folder for some reason.

I have tried installing selenium three different times across different VMs, using venv, moving selenium all of the place.  I am LOST.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:  I removed the '/usr/bin/' per @L3viathan and ran it.  My new error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Couldn't make anything work anymore so I started up another fresh Ubuntu VM and have only done the following commands.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip install selenium
```

And then I ran my program and got the geckodriver error. So I downloaded the geckodriver. and moved it to `/usr/bin/`

```
$ sudo cp geckodriver /usr/bin/
```

ran program and get EXACT same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
        self.service.start()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 64, in start
        stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Did you install the Selenium Python bindings? run $ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo pip install selenium

Comment: Why are you giving `'/usr/bin/'` as an argument? [The first argument is a firefox profile](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver), and `'/usr/bin'` doesn't seem to make sense for any of the possible arguments.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 I have installed them using that command.  I am not getting an error saying no selenium package.

Comment: @L3viathan I was putting that in there as the location for the geckodriver because I was getting an error about selenium not finding it.  I removed it and ran the program.  Update error is above.

Comment: Fair enough. What version of firefox?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Mozilla Firefox 47.0

Comment: Take a look at [selenium-firefox-support-matrix](https://github.com/santiycr/selenium-firefox-support-matrix).  Look [here](http://www.inkhorn.ca/selenium-python-on-ubuntu-using-firefox/) also.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 I have version 3.0.0.b2 so how do I know which Firefox I can use?

Comment: Windows 10 – FIREFOX v 49.0, Linux Firefox v 47.1